# relation *db_name* does not exist postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to set up an ubuntu server with postgres(following digitalocean tuorial).

I `ssh`'d to the server as root user, from there created a user named 'justin', gave that user admin privileges as instructed. Switched to 'justin', installed python, django, pip, etc and postgres. From here the tutorial said type `sudo -u postgres psql`
, I did this. From here I created a db 'jobzumodb' and user 'jobzumojustin'. I am now trying to grant privileges of that db to this new user: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON jobzumodb TO jobzumojustin;` and it returns `ERROR:  relation "jobzumodb" does not exist`. However if I `postgres=#  \l` I see:

```
                              List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding | Collate |  Ctype  |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+---------+---------+-----------------------
 jobzumodb | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres         +
           |          |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres+
           |          |          |         |         | admin=CTc/postgres
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 |
```

Anyone know what is causing this?

Note: when I created the db I created it with: `CREATE DATABASE jobzumoDB;`. And was trying to access it for a long time as 'jobzumoDB' and not 'jobzumodb', before learning the `\l` command and that it saved as 'jobzumodb' because I did not pass it in quotes. Anyway, not sure if this could be having an effect.

Thanks for any help.

Another edit: upon rereading this I realized I am using the 'postgres' user (I see `postgres=#`), should I be using the 'jobzumojustin' user and `jobzumojustin=#` ? Also, I checked to see if 'jobzumojustin' exists, it does, but does not have anything listed under 'list of roles and attributes'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you forgot the database keyword. It should be:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE jobzumodb TO jobzumojustin;
```